# "super" number in python

Tags: python, math

I have a problem with the task. The task is:

> We say that number 1 is a super number. If a number x is super, then
> the numbers 2x and 3x are also super. For example, since the number 1
> is super, then the numbers 2 and 3 are super. As 2 and 3 are super,
> then the numbers 4, 6 and 9 are super, and so on. At the same time,
> numbers 10 and 7 are not super. Write a program that asks the user to
> enter a natural number n. The program prints whether the entered
> number is super.

And this is what I have done so far

```
num = int(input("Enter a natural number "))
if num <= 0:
    print("That is not a natural number")
else:
    if num % 5 == 0 or num % 7 == 0 or num % 11 == 0 or num % 13 == 0:
        print("Number is not super.")
    elif num == 1 or num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0 or num % 8 == 0 or num % 9 == 0:
        print("Number is super")
    else:
        print("Number is not super.")
```

[image: the pydramid of numbers goes here]

The problem is that for some numbers like 62 it says that it is a super number, but it ain't..

Comment: It is not obvious how the conditions in your program follow from the task description. Could it be that the math is wrong? The task sounds to me like the idea is to solve it with recursion, not a closed-form solution - because whether a number `n` is super depends on whether `n/2` and `n/3` are super

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `num % 5 == 0` means? How does the answer to that help you decide whether the number is super? In your own words, what is the logical process you want to use in order to determine whether the number is super? It seems like you really have a math / number theory question, not a programming question.

Comment: (Hint: what's special about the numbers `5`, `7`, `11` and `13`? Can you think of more numbers that belong in this sequence? Do you see why this causes a problem for your approach?) (Hint: do you know what a *prime factorization* is? What is the prime factorization of `62`?)

Comment: 5 is lowest number that is not "super" and my idea is if it is divisible by 5 it cannot be super, idk

Comment: @Ole before you write the program, it's almost always useful to first think some examples through yourself. How do you figure out, step by step, whether a number I give you (say `62`) is super or not? You need to work with the definition, not some arbitrary guess. So .. either the number is `1`, or there is a way to find a `x` that is super such that either `2*x = number` or `3 * x = number`. How do you do this backwards?

Comment: @lucidbrot you mean dividing it by 2 or 3 until I reach 1 ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking of. Maybe there is also a way to do it with just some math formula, but I'm not seeing that currently and this way is easy enough to implement. Also note that @KarlKnechtel has an alternative suggestion to the recursive approach (which I am suggesting) that is based on the same logic

Comment: (I wasn't offering a concrete suggestion - although I could have - but simply asking Socratic questions to direct thought.)

Comment: ( @KarlKnechtel Well, maybe you did not intend to do so, but your comment made me think of an alternative solution that is actually a two-liner :D I like it! )

Comment: @Ole you are right: if a number is divisible by 5, then it is not super. But if the number is not divisible by 5, then you still don't know whether it's super or not. Numbers divisible by 7 are not super either. Numbers divisible by 11 are not super either. Numbers divisible by 13 are not super either. Numbers divisible by 17 are not super either. Numbers divisible by 19 are not super either. There is an infinity number of divisibilities to check. Of course you can't check them all one by one. So you need to find another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just following the definition of super number:

```
def is_super(k):
    if k == 1: return True
    if k % 2 == 0: 
        return is_super(k / 2)
    if k % 3 == 0:           
        return is_super(k / 3)
    return False
```

Some testing

```
print(is_super(9))
True
print(is_super(14))
False
print(is_super(32))
True
print(is_super(62))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you jumped in without first figuring out how you'd work it out manually.

Personally, I think the easiest way to start this would be recursively, though it'll be very inefficient with large numbers, so it's up to you if you then want to go and optimise it after doing the first version. I got it working pretty easily, but since it's a problem you need to solve, I'm not going to just copy and paste the answer.

It works something like this (psuedocode):

```
def is_super(i):
    if i is below 1: not a super
    if i is 1: is a super
    if i is above 1: check if i/2 or i/3 is a super
```

Comment: That's a bit weird. What does `is_super(5)` do? How do you check whether 5/2 or 5/3 is a super?

Comment: I was going off the assumption of what he wrote in the problem - `1 is super`, and `2x and 3x` are super. Going by that logic, 5 shouldn't be super, because no super numbers can be multiplied by 2 or 3 to make it.

Comment: I was specifically being vague in that part lol - since it's all quite simple, if I was being more precise, I may as well just have written the python code anyway :P   This was more meant as a base point to work from

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice recursive solutions here, I'll propose a non-recursive one. As some of the comments hint, *super* numbers have a tell-tale factorization: they are all of the form 2<sup>x</sup> * 3<sup>y</sup> for x, y >= 0, and every integer of that form is a *super* number. This should become clear after some study because the only way to get a super number is to multiply an existing one by 2 or 3, and we start with 1. That leads to the following code to test for superness:

```py
def is_super(n: int) -> bool:
   if n < 1:
       return False

   while n % 3 == 0:
       n //= 3

   return n & (n - 1) == 0;  // Suggested by @KellyBundy
```

I tried to find shortcut way to test for superness but failed to find anything better than this.

Comment: I guess you could remove the first loop and finish with `return n & (n-1) == 0` instead.

Comment: Or *if* the numbers were limited, let's say to 32 bit ints, then maybe just `return 6**32 % n == 0`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: that's a good observation, I'll add it to my answer when I get a chance later.

Answer (score -1):

```
num = int(input("Enter a natural number "))
if num <= 0:
    print("That is not a natural number")
else:
    if num % 3 == 0:
        while num % 3 == 0:
            num = num / 3
        print(num)
        if num == 1 or num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0:
            print("Number is super")
        else:
            print("Number is not super")
    elif num % 2 == 0:
        while num % 2 == 0:
            num = num / 2
        print(num)
        if num == 1 or num % 2 == 0 or num % 3 == 0:
            print("Number is super")
        else:
            print("Number is not super")
    else:
        print("Number is not super")
```

This is what I've done so far but I don't think it will work for large numbers ?

Comment: Try it on 30. Does the result seem correct to you?

Comment: In fact, even on 1 it returns a wrong result.